# jQuery autocomplete - fill 2 input fields with label and value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The input field I am searching in has to display the label after I select the item and the second field needs to be filled with the value the autocomplete-request gets from the source.

What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lj7PC/

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    // fill the two fields with the label and value from source              
    this.value = ui.item.label;
    $('#prid').value=ui.item.value;
}
```

Comment: `$('#prid').val(ui.item.label)` ? http://jsfiddle.net/f2aZ8/

Comment: this fills the value in both fields ... label should go in the first input field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
$('#prid').value=ui.item.value;
```

Should Be:

```
$('#prid').val(ui.item.value);
```

In addition if you want the original input box to display the selected item you would need:

```
 select: function( event, ui ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
            PK.render(ui.item.value);
        }
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj7PC/5/)